# Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n)$ with $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}.$ Prove that $ \sqrt[3]2 \notin F$.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

So I tried by claiming each extension $ \mathbb{Q}(a_i) $ was of degree 2 because of the $a_i^2 \in \mathbb{Q}.$ Apparently that wasn't necessarily true.
I said that $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]2) $ was a degree 3 extension and $F$ had degree $2^n$ so, it wasn't possible. But apparently that isn't necessarily true? SO I'm not too sure how to do it.

Fyi, this was a homework problem but no solutions were given and so, just wanna know how to do it, or get some help.

Comment: The degree theorem implies it because $3\nmid 2^m$, you are right. You just have to consider the right tower of field extensions.

Comment: $F$ doesn't necessarily have degree $2^n$—consider for example $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n$. But you should be able to show (using a tower of extensions) that its degree is some power of $2$.

Comment: Probably the objection is: for example if $a_1 = a_2 = \sqrt{2}$ then it satisfies the conditions but $[F : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ not $2^2$.  For a slightly more complex counterexample, consider $a_1 = \sqrt{2}$, $a_2 = \sqrt{3}$, $a_3 = \sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $[\mathbb{Q}(a_1,\dots,a_{k+1}:\mathbb{Q}(a_1,\dots,a_k)]=1$ or $2$.